# Comparing two files and displaying diffrences in excel?

Tags: excel

[image: Example]

I am trying to compare some huge files, and make sure that what is in the "Master Table" is in the "Other tables" as well. The problem I am running into is none of the "other tables" have the same number of ID's so I am using INDEX and MATCH. It is working fine, however there is so many it would take me forever to go to each and find what is exactly wrong.  I was just hoping I could push it a little further. Instead of showing N/A when a partial match is found have some formula that shows me the row at the very least that did not match, because technically all of them should match the master.

In other words if the ID is found I would like to see what row or rows if possible that are not matching after the ID. I want to see the differences of the rows so I can go fix them in my program.

Here is what I am currently using currently:

```
=INDEX($E$6:$E$15,MATCH(1,($G$6=$A$6:$A$15)*(H6=$B$6:$B$15)*(I6=$C$6:$C$15)*(J6=$D$6:$D$15),0))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: instead of having static text in 'other table', why not use a formula to lookup the correct values from the master.  something like `=VLOOKUP($F4,$A$4:$D$21,2)`

Comment: Good question, The other table is just a dump of data from a program. I have to actually manualy go into the program to change anything. It would be nice if I could just upload the data like that. :)